# spl_autoload with namespace php

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoloader

I am makeing a small framework for scheduled job that are run by a nodejs external process. I would like to use an auto loader but for some reason data is not getting to it. I am also using namespaces. Here is what my folder structure looks like:

```
Library
  |_ Core
     |_ JobConfig.php
  |_ Utilities
     |_ Loader.php
  |_ Scheduled
     |_ SomeJob.php
  |_ Config.php
```

My `Config.php` just has some definitions and an instance of my `Loader.php`.

Loader.php looks like:

```
public function __constructor()
{
    spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'coreLoader'));
    spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'utilitiesLoader'));
}

private function coreLoader($class)
{
    echo $class;
    return true;
}

private function utilitiesLoader($lass)
{
    echo $class;
    return true;
}
```

So for my `SomeJob.php` I am including `Config.php` and then try to instantiate JobConfig.php when it fails. My namespaces look like `Library\Core\JobConfig` and so on. I am not sure if this is the best approach without the ability to bootsrapt things. But I am not seeing the echo's from the loader before it fails.

**Edit:**

I tried the sugestion by @Layne but did not work. I am still getting a class not found and seems like the class in not getting in the spl stack. [Here](http://pastebin.com/0Gqrz03H) is a link to the code

Comment: Which class can it not find? Have you checked that it is in the correct directory and has the corresponding namespace to that directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually use namespaces in the same way you're using your directory structure, this should be rather easy.

```
<?php
namespace Library {
    spl_autoload_register('\Library\Autoloader::default_autoloader');

    class Autoloader {
        public static function default_autoloader($class) {
            $class = ltrim($class, '\\');

            $file = __DIR__ . '/../';
            if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($class, '\\')) {
                $namespace = substr($class, 0, $lastNsPos);
                $class     = substr($class, $lastNsPos + 1);
                $file .= str_replace('\\', '/', $namespace) . '/';
            }

            $file .= $class . '.php';
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Put that into your Library directory and require it on a higher level. Hopefully I didn't mess that one up, didn't test it.

EDIT: Fixed path.

Answer (score 0):

use this class to index of your project, just replace `WP_CONTENT_DIR` with another directory level to scan php files, this class automatically include files:

```
    <?php

class autoloader
{

    public static function instance()
    {
        static $instance = false;
        if( $instance === false )
        {
            // Late static binding
            $instance = new static();
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * @param $dir_level directory level is for file searching
     * @param $php_files_json_name name of the file who all the PHP files will be stored inside it
     */
    private function export_php_files($dir_level, $php_files_json_name)
    {

        $filePaths = array(mktime());
        /**Get all files and directories using iterator.*/
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir_level));

        foreach ($iterator as $path) {
            if (is_string(strval($path)) and pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php') {
                $filePaths[] = strval($path);
            }
        }

        /**Encode and save php files dir in a local json file */
        $fileOpen = fopen($dir_level . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $php_files_json_name, 'w');
        fwrite($fileOpen, json_encode($filePaths));
        fclose($fileOpen);
    }

    /**
     * @param $php_files_json_address json file contains all the PHP files inside it
     * @param $class_file_name name of the class that was taken from @spl_autoload_register_register plus .php extension
     * @return bool Succeeding end of work
     */
    private function include_matching_files($php_files_json_address, $class_file_name)
    {
        static $files;
        $inc_is_done = false;

        if ($files == null) {
            $files = json_decode(file_get_contents($php_files_json_address), false);
        }

        /**Include matching files here.*/
        foreach ($files as $path) {
            if (stripos($path, $class_file_name) !== false) {
                require_once $path;
                $inc_is_done = true;
            }
        }
        return $inc_is_done;
    }

    /**
     * @param $dir_level directory level is for file searching
     * @param $class_name name of the class that was taken from @spl_autoload_register
     * @param bool $try_for_new_files Try again to include new files, that this feature is @true in development mode
     * it will renew including file each time after every 30 seconds @see $refresh_time.
     * @return bool Succeeding end of work
     */
    public function request_system_files($dir_level, $class_name, $try_for_new_files = false)
    {
        $php_files_json = 'phpfiles.json';
        $php_files_json_address = $dir_level . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $php_files_json;
        $class_file_name = $class_name . '.php';
        $files_refresh_time = 30;

        /**Include required php files.*/
        if (is_file($php_files_json_address)) {

            $last_update = json_decode(file_get_contents($php_files_json_address), false)[0];

            if ((mktime() - intval($last_update)) < $files_refresh_time || !$try_for_new_files) {
                return $this->include_matching_files($php_files_json_address, $class_file_name);
            }

        }

        $this->export_php_files($dir_level, $php_files_json);
        return $this->include_matching_files($php_files_json_address, $class_file_name);

    }

    /**
     * Make constructor private, so nobody can call "new Class".
     */
    private function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Make clone magic method private, so nobody can clone instance.
     */
    private function __clone()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Make sleep magic method private, so nobody can serialize instance.
     */
    private function __sleep()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Make wakeup magic method private, so nobody can unserialize instance.
     */
    private function __wakeup()
    {
    }


}

/**
 * Register autoloader.
 */
try {
    spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
        $autoloader = autoloader::instance();

        return $autoloader->request_system_files(WP_CONTENT_DIR, $className, true);
    });
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
    die;
}
```